# Value of HTML Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble checking the value of a checkbox in an html form. Here is the html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="termcheck"> I Agree to the<a target="_blank" href="">Terms of Service.</a>
```

and here is my js

```
$("#submit_btn").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($("#termcheck").checked)
});
```

This gives me "undefined" every time. I just want to be able to see if the box has been checked or not.

Comment: use [**.is()**](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to check whether the checkbox is checked or not - `alert($("#termcheck").is(':checked'))`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#submit_btn").on("click", function(event){
event.preventDefault();
alert($("#termcheck")[0].checked)
});
```

check this JSFiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/5cxcL2wp/4/